# Construct class instance from class object in java

Tags: java, class

I need to create a new instance of a class from an array of class objects like this:

```
static Class[] spells = {Fireball.class, Iceball.class};
```

So when I want to call the fireball i should be able to do something like

```
Spell Currentspell = new spells[0](posx, posy);
```

Fireball and Iceball is by the way child classes of Spell.

How do i do this?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: It may be better for you to tell us what effect you're trying to achieve rather than what code you're currently using to try to achieve it. There may be a cleaner way of doing all this, once we know what all this is. My code smell radar always goes up when I see heavy use of reflection in an application that typically doesn't need to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Constructor constructor = spells[0].getConstructor(int.class, int.class);
Spell Currentspell = (Spell)constructor.newInstance(posx, posy);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this:

`try {
Constructor constructor = spells[0].getConstructor(Integer.class, Integer.class);
Spell Currentspell = (Spell)constructor.newInstance(100, 100);
} catch (Throwable e) {
System.err.println(e);
}`

But it doesn't give me an error or create the class instance

Comment: @KristofferDorph is `Currentspell` instance null? try catching  `Exception e` rather than `Throwable e`. Also, can you post the constructor for `Fireball` that you are trying to use ?

Comment: Thanks alot, got it working! :-) Was a little mistake from my part, but you solved it, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke the appropriate constructor of the class by reflection.

See the "Creating new objects" section at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`getConstructor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method to get the specific constructor you want and then call [`newInstance()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) on the constructor object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing you will want to narrow down the type of class that can be stored in your array. And second, your instantiation code is off. Without going into wether this is the best way to accomplish this, here is some (better) code:

```
static Class<Spell>[] spells = new Class<Spell>[] { Fireball.class, Iceball.class };
Spell currentSpell = spells[someIndex].newInstance();
```